# Most elegant way of using the getline function?

Tags: c++, string

Which is the most elegant way to use the getline function with very simple std::strings (not arrays)?

For arrays I like

```
std::cin.getline(string1, 20);
```

but this doesn't work with std::strings, is there something equivalent or dare I say better?

There seems to be a lot of conflicting answers online for all kinds of situations, and many of them seems very long-winded to me, so...what would you recommend?

I ask as when I use

```
std::string string1;

std::cout << "Input string\n";    //123 tgd 4

std::getline(std::cin, string1);

std::cout << string1 << "\n";    //tgd 4
```

The output only starts after the first blank space

Comment: Are you reading an entire line or only 20 characters of the line?

Comment: http://ideone.com/Vg6cUI `std::getline()` works fine in your example.

Answer (score 2):

There is [`std::getline(std::cin, string1);`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).

Comment: The reason I ask is because I have been using this and for some reason my compiler will only output the string after the first blank space

Comment: Please update your usage and example input to question.